# how to get element of list without string

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list like:

```
my_list = ['[:,y+1,x+1]', '[:,y+1,x-1]']
my_list[0]
```

gives:

```
'[:,y+1,x+1]'
```

How to get only

```
[:,y+1,x+1]
```

Why I need this: I am trying to read netcdf file with the with the coordinates from the list, something like:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset    
fd = Dataset(ncfile,'r')    
fd.variables['t2m']my_list[0]
```

where x and y are predefined.

Comment: the elements are string, so you need to manually identify the list elements and to convert them into lists.

Comment: better if you show how you got `my_list`. whether you wanted it to be a list of lists or only strings?

Comment: @VanPeer I have created my_list manually. I guess only strings will work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are looking for `np.s_` which allows you to 'freeze' indexing expressions. Try

```
my_list = [np.s_[:,y+1,x+1], np.s_[:,y+1,x-1]]
```

Comment: again the my_list[0] gives : (slice(None, None, None), 22, 41) which does not work for fd.variables['t2m']my_list[0]

Comment: @bikuser Did you put it in square brackets `fd.variables['t2m'][my_list[0]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the right answer, but an attempt. To be able to execute something like:

```
fd.variables['t2m'][:,y+1,x+1]
```

Then you should only store tuples here:

```
my_list = [(5,5),(3,3)]
```

And define y and x before the command like this:

```
y,x = my_list[0]
```